# PrintWriter not working java web service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, printwriter

I have a java project with threads which writes info in a log file.
What i was doing was the following:

create the file when creating a Process( `PrintWriter file` its an attribute):

```
public Process(int id){
        id_proc= id;
        try {
            file=new PrintWriter("log_acuerdo_" + this.id_proc +".txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Then, when i wanted to write something in it:

```
file.println("P0" + msj.emisor + " " + msj.id);
```

Then, after all threads were done writing i did this:

```
for(int i=0; i<cant_proc; i++)
    ((Process)procesos[i]).file.close();
```

This was working perfectly fine. 
Then, i wanted to change the project and use REST instead, i mean, web services. The whole project is working ok, except it's not creating any file or nothing is being written.

Any idea why?

Comment: Explain what happens *exactly*, not "I don't know", but a proper description of what happens and under what conditions.

Comment: The files are not being created. I saw this could happened if the file wasn't being properly closed, but i'm doing it.

Comment: Have you looked into your server logs to find any exceptions? Are you sure you are looking for the files in the correct directory? You seem to be using a relative file name, do you know what it is relative to?

Comment: yeah. It means it's being created inside the project. I believe i'm looking into the right place because when it was a regular java project i knew where to find them. The server doesn't throw any exception

Comment: No, it doesn't mean it is being created inside the project. The project doesn't exist at runtime. It means it is created in the current working directory of the servlet container which is running  your code. Probably its 'bin' directory.

Comment: yeah, you're right. Mine was a poor explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using REST, then your files are being created inside your eclipse folder. Take a look there. There are a bunch of other folders like 'p2', 'configuration', 'readme' and other stuff.

Comment: thanks man!! you were right! I don't know why when i run it in XOS they're not being created but when i ran it on windows they were created inside the eclipse folder.
thanks!!!